# How to set Hyperlinks in the mail sent from Unix Box?

Tags: bash

I am sending a mail from my unix machine to my Outlook. I want to add a hyperlink to the content of the mail so that I can click on that hyperlink so that it will go to that particular line.. Please help..

eg..
Subject: Testsmail

para1  para2  para 3 ... hyperlinks to be set here

Sabarish bnadzsbcl blkbklbaklb lkbkl bklb lbkbklb klb kl blkbklbbnlb blblkbklblkbklblkblblkbklbklbklbklbladvgfuqggvwhipowehopvhwpohpohvwhbhahhkvk

Happy ksankqihfoihihfihiqhfihqiwfhoiqhfihqfoihiqhihqfihihqfehiqhfihfoiqhifhihqfoiiwhfihqoihiqhcbakbkbckabkcbbakbcjabkjbckabkabkbkacbkcakjbkcakba

Sad a';sjcf;la;fja;;fjajfajjfclaj;lajsljf;ljaljfaljvgaswdegfuewweifwiuggfwguiqw

Here If i click on para1 it should come to Sabarish..

Comment: You would need to format in mime encoded messages and provide say a HTML rendition of your message where the links are clickable.

Comment: set the headers straight with a content-type html, then `<a href=#nameId>para</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way to do it from a BASH script. You need to set the content type of the email to `HTML` to do what you want.

```
echo "<html><body><a href="http://www.domain.com">Link text</a></body></html>" > mailbody.html
#You can add more text to the mailbody.html file, but in html format
MAILFROM=admin@domain.com
MAILTO=receiver@domain.com
SUBJECT="HTML Email"

( cat <<HERE; cat mailbody.html ) | sendmail -oi -t
From: ${MAILFROM}
To: ${MAILTO}
Subject: ${SUBJECT}
Content-Type: text/html

HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make html page

## para1 links are like this:

To link to an anchor you need to: 
1 Create a link pointing to the anchor
2 Create the anchor itself.

An anchor is created using the  tag. 
If you want to create an anchor called chapter4, you simply add this line where you want the anchor to be:

After doing this, you can make a link pointing to the anchor using the normal  tag, like this:

Click here to read chapter 4.

Note:
When linking to an anchor on a page you need to put a # in front of the anchor.

When you link to an anchor on the same page, simply enter

para4

After that, you should mail html page as MIME attachment . Use mpack program to this.

Comment: How can we add an anchor ?? Since i am a minnow in this can you be a bit more elaborate??